# How to disable screenshots and javascript for PhantomJS in python selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am scraping in a python/selenium framework using phantomJS on windows. First, I tried to disable javascript and screenhsots with selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("phantomjs.exe", desired_capabilities = dcap)
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS["phantomjs.page.settings.javascriptEnabled"] = False
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS["phantomjs.takesScreenshot"] = False
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS["phantomjs.page.clearMemoryCash"] = False
```

However, when I have a look at `ghostdriver.log`, `Session.negotiatedCapabilities` includes:

```
browserName:phantomjs
version:2.1.1
driverName:ghostdriver
driverVersion:1.2.0
platform:windows-7-32bit
javascriptEnabled:true   # Should be false
takesScreenshot:true     # Should be false
```

Therefore, I think I need to disable both parameters during `onInitialized=function()`, similar to the below code snippet:

```
phantom_exc_uri='/session/$sessionId/phantom/execute'
driver.command_executor._commands['executePhantomScript'] = ('POST', phantom_exc_uri)
initScript="""             
this.onInitialized=function() {
    var page=this;
   ### disable javascript and screenshots here ###
}
"""
driver.execute('executePhantomScript',{'script': initScript, 'args': []})
```

**Q1: How come I can set *some* phantomJS specs in `webdriver.DesiredCapabilities`, but others not? Is this my mistake or some bug?**

**Q2: Is it reasonable to accomplish this during onInitialized or am I on the wrong way?**

**Q2: If so, how to disable JS and screenshots during onInitialized?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have raised quite a few queries in your question. Let me try to address them all. A simple workflow with `Selenium v3.8.1`, `ghostdriver v1.2.0` and `phantomjs v2.1.1 Browser` shows us that the following **Session.negotiatedCapabilities** are passed by default :

- **`"browserName":"phantomjs"`**
- **`"version":"2.1.1"`**
- **`"driverName":"ghostdriver"`**
- **`"driverVersion":"1.2.0"`**
- **`"platform":"windows-8-32bit"`**
- **`"javascriptEnabled":true`**
- **`"takesScreenshot":true`**
- **`"handlesAlerts":false`**
- **`"databaseEnabled":false`**
- **`"locationContextEnabled":false`**
- **`"applicationCacheEnabled":false`**
- **`"cssSelectorsEnabled":true`**
- **`"webStorageEnabled":false`**
- **`"rotatable":false`**
- **`"acceptSslCerts":false`**
- **`"nativeEvents":true`**
- **`"proxy":{"proxyType":"direct"}}`**

So by default it was mandated that to establish a successful session through `PhantomJSDriver` and `Ghost Browser` combination the following **`Capabilities`** were a minimum requirement.

Then the users had the `DesiredCapabilities` class at their disposal to tweak the capabilities. But there are certain capabilities which are **minimum requirement** to create a successful `Ghost Browser` session.

**javascriptEnabled** is such a property which is mandatory. Till a few releases back `Selenium` did allow to tweak the **javascriptEnabled** attribute to **false**. But now **`WebDriver`** being a **`W3C Recommendation Candidate`** the mandatory capabilities cannot be over-ridden anymore through `DesiredCapabilities` at user level.

Even if you try to tweak them at `user level`, `WebDriver` will override them to default while configuring the `capabilities`.

So, though you have tried the following :

```
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS["phantomjs.page.settings.javascriptEnabled"] = False
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS["phantomjs.takesScreenshot"] = False
```

The properties **javascriptEnabled** and **takesScreenshot** defaults to required mandatory configuration.

---

### Update

As you mentioned in your comment `What about changing those AFTER the Ghostdriver session is established, i.e. page.onInitialized` the straight answer is **No**.

Once the `capabilities` are **freezed** and **negotiated** to initialize a `Browsing Session` the `capabilities` holds true till the particular `session is active`. So you can't change any of the `capabilities` once the `session is established`. To change the `capabilities` you have to configure the `WebDriver` instance again.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed and easy-to-understand answer! You are saying that due to minimum requirements of GhostDriver, some of phantomJS's caps can't be changed. What about changing those AFTER the Ghostdriver session is established, i.e. page.onInitialized (Q2)? If that's not possible also, you have effectively solved my problem.

Comment: Updated my answer. Let me know if you have any counter questions.